# Precise Selection in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have several images I need to cut out from specific places but in different PSDs.

Say I want Selection Rectangle 200,300,400,500. How can I just type this in and get that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Selection with transform controls]

Make a selection and choose from the menu: `Select` → `Transform selection` → type in values in the options panel.